# How do I create 3x3 matrices?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 2D list containing these values:

```
text = [[4, 3, 8, 9, 5, 1, 2, 7, 6], [8, 3, 4, 1, 5, 9, 6, 7, 2], 
[6, 1, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2, 9, 4], [6, 9, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4], 
[6, 1, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4], [6, 1, 3, 2, 9, 4, 8, 7, 5]]
```

For instance, text[i] should be printed like this:

```
4 3 8
9 5 1
2 7 6
```

But my matrix prints this:

```
   r = 6
   m = []
    for i in range(r):
        m.append([int(x) for x in text[i]])
    for i in m:
        print (i) 
>>
    4 3 8 9 5 1 2 7 6 
    8 3 4 1 5 9 6 7 2
    6 1 8 7 5 3 2 9 4 
    6 9 8 7 5 3 2 1 4 
    6 1 8 7 5 3 2 1 4 
    6 1 3 2 9 4 8 7 5
```

Comment: If you're doing numerical work with matrices, you may want to look at [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).

Comment: Are you trying to create a 3D list from the 2D list's data or just print it out like it was one?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [numpy](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial). First, convert your list into numpy array. Then, take an element and reshape it to 3x3 matrix.

```
import numpy as np

text = [[4, 3, 8, 9, 5, 1, 2, 7, 6], [8, 3, 4, 1, 5, 9, 6, 7, 2],
[6, 1, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2, 9, 4], [6, 9, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4],
[6, 1, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4], [6, 1, 3, 2, 9, 4, 8, 7, 5]]

text = np.array(text)

print text[0].reshape((3, 3))
print text[1].reshape((3, 3))
```

Output:

```
[[4 3 8]
 [9 5 1]
 [2 7 6]]

[[8 3 4]
 [1 5 9]
 [6 7 2]]
```

With numpy, you are really working with matrices

Comment: One of these days I'll learn how to use numpy and all that magic will be mine!

Answer (score 3):

```
def print9_as_3x3(list9):
    for i in 0, 3, 6:
        for j in 0, 1, 2:
            print(list9[i+j], end= ' ')
    print()
```

This can of course be easily generalized (using `range`s instead of those literal tuples) but I'm trying to keep it as simple as feasible.

The Q's subject talks about **creating** matrices, which this code doesn't do, but the Q's body's all about **printing** instead, so I've focused on that!  Please clarify (edit your Q) and comment if you want something different...

Answer (score 2):

Use the grouper recipe [referred to here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks) to split each list into 3's, then print each set of three.

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
    # zip_longest is new in Python3

for matrix in text:
    for chunk in grouper(matrix, 3):
        print(chunk)
    print() # empty line in between each 3x3
```

RESULT:

```
(4, 3, 8)
(9, 5, 1)
(2, 7, 6)

(8, 3, 4)
(1, 5, 9)
(6, 7, 2)

(6, 1, 8)
(7, 5, 3)
(2, 9, 4)

(6, 9, 8)
(7, 5, 3)
(2, 1, 4)

(6, 1, 8)
(7, 5, 3)
(2, 1, 4)
```

To make the literal output from the question, you'll have to do a bit of formatting but it shouldn't be too bad. Something like:

```
for matrix in text:
    for chunk in grouper(matrix, 3):
        print(" ".join(map(str, chunk)))
    print()
```

RESULT:

```
4 3 8
9 5 1
2 7 6

8 3 4
1 5 9
6 7 2

6 1 8
7 5 3
2 9 4

6 9 8
7 5 3
2 1 4

6 1 8
7 5 3
2 1 4

6 1 3
2 9 4
8 7 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for a, b ,c in (x[i:i+3] for x in text for i in range(0,len(x),3)):
    print(a,b,c)

4 3 8
9 5 1
2 7 6
8 3 4
1 5 9
6 7 2
6 1 8
7 5 3
2 9 4
6 9 8
7 5 3
2 1 4
6 1 8
7 5 3
2 1 4
6 1 3
2 9 4
8 7 5
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear to me what you're after, so here's one guess:

```
text = [[4, 3, 8, 9, 5, 1, 2, 7, 6], [8, 3, 4, 1, 5, 9, 6, 7, 2],
        [6, 1, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2, 9, 4], [6, 9, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4],
        [6, 1, 8, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4], [6, 1, 3, 2, 9, 4, 8, 7, 5]]

# convert to 3D list in-place
for i, data in enumerate(text):
    text[i] = [[data[0], data[1], data[2]],
               [data[3], data[4], data[5]],
               [data[6], data[7], data[8]]]

# utility for print a 3x3 matrix         
def formatrix(label, matrix):
    indent = len(label)
    return '\n'.join((label + ', '.join(map(str, matrix[0])),
                      indent*' ' + ', '.join(map(str, matrix[1])),
                      indent*' ' + ', '.join(map(str, matrix[2]))))

# print each matrix in reformatted list
for i, matrix in enumerate(text):
    print(formatrix('text[%s]: ' % i, matrix))
```

Output:

```
text[0]: 4, 3, 8
         9, 5, 1
         2, 7, 6
text[1]: 8, 3, 4
         1, 5, 9
         6, 7, 2
text[2]: 6, 1, 8
         7, 5, 3
         2, 9, 4
text[3]: 6, 9, 8
         7, 5, 3
         2, 1, 4
text[4]: 6, 1, 8
         7, 5, 3
         2, 1, 4
text[5]: 6, 1, 3
         2, 9, 4
         8, 7, 5
```